# nginx returns status:500 when upstream_cache_status:UPDATING

Tags: webserver, nginx, cache

I use **proxy_cache_use_stale** with **updating** attribute.

I grep my logs for the $upstream_cache_status UPDATING value and found many matchs but I can't reproduce this situation.

Can you please help to create conditions that leads me to the UPDATING in $upstream_cache_status ?!
This is first step for me to find out why 500 instead of 200 returned to client.

Usual log line looks like:

```
... "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 1208 "-" ... - - upstream_cache_status:UPDATING
```

So, the error code 500 returned to the client ;(
By the documentation this should be the cached page and 200 code AFAIR.

What can lead to this issue?

I checked that nginx cache dir have enough space and files inside it not managed by any external utilities.
No errors in error logs.